# Orthogonal to two vectors(4D)

Tags: linear-algebra

I have to vectors $v = (-7,-6,2,-8)$ and $u = (-6,-9,k,-7)$ and I need to find $s$ and $t$ s.t. $w = (s,8,-4,t)$ is orthonal to both $v$ and $u$. I tried doing: $v \cdot w = 0$ and $u \cdot w = 0$  and solving the system of equations, but I got the wrong answer.

EDIT: For $s$ I get $s = 32k + 184$ however, the computer says it won't accept the answer as it wants a number.

[image]

Comment: Well, that's the right way to solve the problem...

Comment: If you show the answer you got, we might be able to help.  Do you mean $k$ to be a variable, a parameter, or is it a typo for a number?

Comment: @RossMillikan I meant $k$ as a variable

Comment: It seems to me that once you've found the value of $k$ in the first part of the problem, you should *use that value* to get a number for $s$ to use as the answer in part $b$.

Comment: @Muphrid Ah yes of course. You are correct. Thank you!